Adjusting existing VBA code to keep source format of consolidated files
I have code which takes data from 6 workbooks and consolidates into one. This works but when I copy and paste the data into the consolidated workbook it doesn't keep the source formatting. Is there a way to modify this code to achieve this? Current code below:
Option Explicit
Sub ConsolidateWorkbooksIntoSheets()
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Specify the folder path where the workbooks are located
    folderPath = "C:\Users\sean.stenning\OneDrive - TTC\Desktop\Res Accounting\OSB reports\2024\Data\" ' Change this to your folder path
    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
    
    ' List of workbook names to copy data from
    fileArray = Array("BVCANS.xlsx", "CHCANS.xlsx", "IVCANS.xlsx", "LGCANS.xlsx", "CSCANS.xlsx", "TTCANS.xlsx")
    
    ' Create a new workbook for the consolidated data
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add

    
    ' Loop through each file name listed in fileArray
    For i = LBound(fileArray) To UBound(fileArray)
        ' Construct the full file path
        fileName = folderPath & fileArray(i)
        
        ' Debug statement to print file path
        Debug.Print fileName
        
        ' Check if the file exists before opening
        If Dir(fileName) <> "" Then
            ' Open the source workbook
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
            
            ' Assume data is in the first worksheet of the source workbook
            Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
            
            ' Add a new sheet in the destination workbook for each source workbook
            Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets.Add(After:=wbDest.Sheets(wbDest.Sheets.Count))
            wsDest.Name = "Consolidated_" & i + 1
            
            ' Copy the data from the source worksheet to the destination worksheet
            wsSource.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("A1")
            
            ' Close the source workbook
            wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Else
            MsgBox "The file " & fileArray(i) & " does not exist in the folder path " & folderPath, vbExclamation
        End If
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "Data consolidation complete!"
    
    
End Sub

Tried to consolidate to file using source formatting but doesn't keep existing data format.

wsSource.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("A1"): 'Copy copies the formatting too, so it's not clear why you're experiencing something different. What specific formatting is not being copied?

Instead of adding a new sheet and copying the range content, you could create a copy of the source sheet in wbDest.  It's not clear what the issue is though - as BigBen notes your code should already do what you want.

Maybe the formatting in question is conditional formatting?

Thanks for the advice - it's the width and height of the columns and rows that are different when copied. In the original sheets they are set to certain values, but when copied hey default to 8.09 width and 14.50 height.

Consider copying the entire sheets instead of copying their content, as suggested by @Tim Williams
